# Laravel: queue:listen PDOException: could not find driver

Tags: laravel, queue

OS Ubuntu.
Site working!
But if i run

```
queue:listen
```

I getting an error

```
PDOException: could not find driver
```

Configuration:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

sync:

```
'sync' => [
      'driver' => 'database',
      'table'  => 'jobs',
      'queue'  => 'default',
      'expire' => 60,
 ],
```

Comment: A PDO Exception is thrown where there are problems with the database connection, check your database configuration, it's not a queue problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly run in terminal:

```
php artisan queue:table
```

```
php artisan migrate
```

.env:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

Then run in terminal:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

But I strongly recommend using Supervisor.

You should also read the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues